# Task.run takes two threads in an asp .net request?

Tags: asynchronous, task, task-parallel-library

Service layer

```
public async Task<string> getAllAsync()
{
   return await WCFMethodAsync();
}
```

Presentation layer

```
public class Customer  : Controller
{
   public async Task<string> Index()
  {
      var r = await Task.Run(getAllAsync());
    return r;

  }
}
```

I will describe what I think is happening. I would like to know if I am wrong.

1. the request takes a thread from ThreadPool
2. `await` returns an incomplete Task
3. `Task.Run` queues a Task to run `getAllAsync`
   3.1. that will take a thread from the ThreadPool.
4. when the `getAllAsync` method finishes the taken thread returns to the group of threads
5. when the service method call end .net is notified and a thread is taken from the group of threads o terminate the request.

Where is the incomplete homework returned to? Since the method was executed inside `Task.Run`.

I would like to know the flow of the whole process.

Since a thread was initially taken from the thread group and task.run takes a work thread, the question is when the task ends the job (wcf) and a thread is taken to finish the request. How many threads were used to process the request?

Answer (score 0):

Your `getAllAsync` method is a I/O bound operation, because you are making a network call to reach your WCF service instance.

That means the `getAllAsync` will be executed by the network driver. It is an asynchronous non-blocking [promise task](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2015/04/a-tour-of-task-part-10-promise-tasks.html). The calling thread is not blocked until the asynchronous I/O operation finishes. When it finishes the ThreadPool will be notified about it.

---

On the other hand the `Task.Run` is design for CPU bound operation.

The `Task.Run` returns a [delegate task](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2015/03/a-tour-of-task-part-9-delegate-tasks.html) and it is used to queue a work on the ThreadPool. That work will be processed by one of the CPU core.

---

So if you put an asynchronous I/O work (kick-off) call on a dedicated Thread then that is just wasting valuable resources.